# AttributeError: 'MySQL' object has no attribute 'cursor'

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to run my Python Script which stores data in MySQL Database.

I am getting this error when running my script

```
File "/root/bot/airdrop-bot/modules/core/mysql.py", line 19, in __del__
    self.cursor.close()
AttributeError: 'MySQL' object has no attribute 'cursor'
```

```html
import mysql.connector

from system import config


class MySQL:
    """Do not touch this class unless you really know what your doing."""
    def __init__(self):
        self.connection = mysql.connector.connect(
            host=config.MYSQL_HOST,
            database=config.MYSQL_DATABASE,
            user=config.MYSQL_USERNAME,
            passwd=config.MYSQL_PASSWORD,
            charset="utf8mb4"
        )
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor(dictionary=True)

    def __del__(self):
        self.cursor.close()
        self.connection.close()

    def execute(self, query, binds=(), get_last_row_id=False):
        self.cursor.execute(query, binds)
        self.connection.commit()
        if get_last_row_id:
            return self.cursor.lastrowid
        else:
            return self.cursor.rowcount

    def fetchall(self, query, binds=()):
        self.cursor.execute(query, binds)
        return self.cursor.fetchall()

    def fetchone(self, query, binds=()):
        self.cursor.execute(query, binds)
        return self.cursor.fetchone()
```

Kindly help in fixing in the error.

Thank You

Comment: Can you share the code that uses the class MySQL?

Comment: I have several files which use this class.

Comment: share one example.

Comment: I figured out that problem lies with every db interaction.

Comment: Maybe reinstalling can fix

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap them in a `try/except` block:

```
def __del__(self):
    for obj in (self.cursor, self.connection):
        try:
            obj.close()
        except:
            # continue silently!
            pass
```

For the case you haven't created a connection and/or cursor, you could make it more dynamically:

```
def __del__(self):
    for obj in ("cursor", "connection"):
        if hasattr(self, obj):
            try:
                getattr(self, obj).close()
            except:
                pass
```

Comment: I tried it but still the error persists : for obj in (self.cursor, self.connection):
AttributeError: 'MySQL' object has no attribute 'cursor'

Comment: @Andy: Edited. Just wondering why you got no cursor.